# Consume Azure Queue message after X number of days

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

Currently, the message in the azure queue gets consumed instantly once it is in the queue. Is there any way where we can let the message stay in the Azure queue for certain number of days, let's say 30 and once it reaches the limit, it should be consumed by the processor or web service?

Any pointers or leads would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Don't move the message into a queue until it's ready to be processed?

Comment: You could [Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay) your messages inside a LogicApp and then post to your queue for processing.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @filburt So, there is no built in mechanism in the azure queue which can stop the message from getting consumed once it is in the queue?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, but that's not the option which I was looking for. I want to post the message in the queue and wait for 30 days to process the message.

Comment: No queuing system that I know of has such a feature - it goes against the fundamental principles of what queuing software is for. My and Filburt's suggestions are more or less the same - you need to find an external way to prevent the message from entering the queue until it's ready to be processed (ie 30 days).

Comment: @gunr2171 Okay. How about using initialVisibilityDelay property and make it invisible for 30 days while adding message to the queue? Something like this?

 AzureQueue.AddMessage(message, initialVisibilityDelay: TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. `initialVisibilityDelay` is meant for that purpose only. Once set, the message will remain invisible to all callers for the duration specified. Once that time period elapses, the message will appear in the queue.

However please note that:

- Once the message is sent with initial visibility delay, there's no way for you to fetch that message before that time elapses.
- Currently maximum value allowed for this is 7 days (thus your 30 day period will not work).
- It should be set to a value smaller than the time-to-live value.